# Uploading file not get displaying by using War file in Tomcat

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, file-upload, war

I am using Ajax file upload.Newly uploaded image not reflected in WAR file.I am inserting only name to the DB. Same thing happens with eclipse also, after uploading each image need to refresh eclipse ide project folder for displaying that image in jsp. Now i need to generate WAR file each time after uploading new image for display in jsp.

Project folder

[image]

Comment: You're supposed to store user data like this outside your servlet container, the webapp folder is not persistent.

Comment: And there is no reverse mapping from you WAR to your project source - so you will _never_ see anything you store in the WAR directory in the server getting reflected in the project in your IDE.

Comment: Btw. you are mixing Maven-Layout (`src/main/webapp`) with "old school" web project layout (`WebContent`). This may lead to further problems...

Comment: How could i solve this issue help me @TobiasLiefke

Comment: Then where should i put upload folder in my project structure @kryger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With Warfile

Set upload directory path to tomact -> webapps -> your project -> upload (directory which you have to keep your files)

2. With Eclipse

Out of synchronization problem is common in eclipse IDE so you have to check this option windows -> preference -> Workspace -> refresh using native hooks or polling.